# Spark Dataframe writes part files to _temporary in instead directly creating partFiles in output directory

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

> Running Spark 2.0.2 in Standalone Cluster Mode; 2 workers and 1 master node

Simple Test; reading pipe delimited file and writing data to csv. Commands below are executed in spark-shell with master-url set

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.option("delimiter","|").option("quote","\u0000").csv("/home/input-files/")
val emailDf=df.filter("_c3='EML'")
emailDf.repartition(100).write.csv("/opt/outputFile/")
```

After executing the cmds above in spark-shell with master url set.

> In `worker1` -> Each part file is created in`/opt/outputFile/_temporary/task-xxxxx-xxx/part-xxx-xxx`
>   In `worker2` -> `/opt/outputFile/part-xxx` => part files are generated directly under outputDirectory specified during write.

**Same thing happens with coalesce(100) or without specifying repartition/coalesce!!!**

***Quesiton***

1) why `worker1` `/opt/outputFile/` output directory doesn't have `part-xxxx` files just like in `worker2`? why `_temporary` directory is created and `part-xxx-xx` files reside in the `task-xxx` directories?

2) Is it because I don't have `HDFS` installed on the cluster!?

Comment: @user8371915 I don't understand the exact reason by looking at the answers for other questions! Could you please explain!

Comment: The write is finalized by moving data from `_temporary` directory to its final destination. This is done by the driver. Since you write to local file system, this just won't work. You might see a  worker correctly finishing the process, if it is co-located with the driver.

Comment: @user8371915  so If I  want `part` files under `outputDirectoryPath`, I need to have HDFS running on the cluster?

Comment: HDFS or other distributed / shared file system.